# delete row with lower value only if there are more than n rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete the row with lower value **only** if there are more than 5 rows in the table.

In this example I want to delete the row with *id* = 4 (value is lower and there are more than 5 rows):

```
|--------------------|
|   id   |   value   |
|--------------------|
|    1         20    |
|--------------------|
|    2         15    |
|--------------------|
|    3         30    |
|--------------------|
|    4         5     |
|--------------------|
|    5         50    |
|--------------------|
|    6         10    |
|--------------------|
```

I wonder if it is possible with one query.

Comment: I don't follow the question.  Are you trying to conditionally delete the row with id = 4?  Or are you trying to delete all but the five highest rows in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `left join` of the same table

```
delete t 
from your_table t
left join 
(
  select id
  from your_table
  order by value desc
  limit 5
) tmp on t.id = tmp.id
where tmp.id is null
```

Comment: This is the answer to a subtly different question